# Python code for determinant of N x N matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, determinants

**my code only works for 3x3 matrix
how to make some modification to work for N x N matrix?**`

```
alist = []

def det(m):
if len(m) > 2:
    for i in range(len(m)):
        new_m = deepcopy(m)
        minor(new_m,i)
        multiplier = m[i][0] * math.pow(-1,i)
        recursive = det(new_m)
        alist.append(multiplier * recursive)
else:
    return (m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[0][1]*m[1][0])

def minor(matrix,row):
    length = len(matrix)
    for i in range(length):
        matrix[i].pop(0)
    matrix.pop(row)
    return matrix
```

Comment: Do you really need to code your own routine? There are many available modules that will do this for you. Check out numpy, for example. (numpy's documentation web pages seem to be offline at the moment--perhaps due to the eastern American snowstorm?)

Comment: limitation for using some of these building functions, have to build up one

Comment: Given that you need to code your own routine, do you have to use the method of minors? That is *very* inefficient for even moderate sizes of N, on the order of N factorial. Could you use Gaussian elimination, for example? I used that for my very first executed computer program--hand-written on cards for a mainframe running BASIC, many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You should use numpy library they offer some great tool to compute the determinant of a matrix:

```
 import numpy
 matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
 det = numpy.linalg.det(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rory Daulton mentions, and as I am pretty sure thousands of people have already mentioned, we cannot compute a general determinant by the method of minors. This method has ONLY theoretical value (for example, to prove that the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal elements). Unless you are specifically asked to implement such a solution (and only for educational purposes) you should go for Gaussian elimination, Choleski factorization, and so on.